# Lightswitch getting 401 in Trace.axd after log in

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an Lightswitch OOB Desktop application. What reasons could there be for getting a 401 error in my trace.axd after a user has logged in? It seems that any data related operations cause a log on window to pop up even after the user has logged in and the trace.axd shows

13  4/17/2013 10:52:33 AM   ApplicationData.svc/Microsoft_LightSwitch_GetCanInformation 401 GET View Details

Comment: I have no user code restricting user permissions on entities.